# How to store and retrieve Swift Data or NSData from MongoDB?

Tags: swift, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store Data object in MongoDB:

It's created using CryptoSwift

```
let bytes = dataString.utf8.map({$0})
let encrypted = try! ChaCha20(key: getAESP(), iv: "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz").encrypt(bytes)
let encryptedData = Data(bytes: encrypted)
```

And sent to the server using NSURLSession:

```
let postData = NSMutableData(data: "patient_id=\(patientID)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
postData.append("&data=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
postData.append(encryptedData)        
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "\(url)api/patient/document")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```

In my model scheme I described data as a Buffer:

```
var DocumentSchema1 = new Schema({
        created_at:Date,
        created_by:String,
        document_type:String,
        document_name:String,
        data: Buffer,
        modifications: [
            {
                modified_by: String,
                modified_at: Date,
                data: Buffer
            }
        ],
        isDeleted: Boolean,
        deleted_at: String,
        deleted_by: String,
  })
```

The problem with this approach is that JSON returned from the web service is a type of buffer not Data, and Swift condition below never gets executed.

```
  if let dataString = dict["data"] as? Data{
```

The question is how can I get the binary data back from Mongo and use it in the Swift?

EDIT2: based on the zaph's answer:
So the data comes as __NSArrayI with elements Int64(35)
The only way I can cast is to `Array<AnyObject>` but I can't convert it to data given this form.

The attempts to cast it to:

- `Array<Int64>`
- [UInt64]
- [UInt8]
- [Int64]
- UnsafeRawPointer

failed.

```
 if let a = dataDict["data"] as? Array<Int64>
```

Comment: Hint: If you use AES from Common Crypto the encryption speed with be ordewrs of magnitude faster.

Comment: Try `init(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer, count: Int)` to create a `Data` object from bytes.

Comment: How would i get the UnsafeRawPointer ?  Please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dataString` is an array of bytes that is badly named:

```
let dataString :[UInt8] = [0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44]
print("dataString: \(dataString)")
let data =  Data(bytes:dataString, count:4)
print("data: \(data)")
print("data as hexadecimal: \(data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())")
```

> Output:

```
dataString: [65, 66, 67, 68]
data: 4 bytes
data as hexadecimal: 41424344
```

Comment: Thank you zaph. I am still struggling with it. Could you have a look at my latest edit? I didn't see your answer until tonight, my notifications must be off.